# Sodium chloride crystal,

Tags: electrostatics

I am studying the potential electric of a sodium chloride crystal, where the actors says:

> To evaluate the potential energy we first observe that every positive
> ion is in a position equivalent to that of every other positive ion. Furthermore,
> although it is perhaps not immediately obvious from Fig. 1.7, the
> arrangement of positive ions around a negative ion is exactly the same as
> the arrangement of negative ions around a positive ion, and so on. Hence
> we may take one ion as a center, it matters not which kind, sum over its
> interactions with all the others, and simply multiply by the total number
> of ions of both kinds. This reduces the double sum in Eq. (1.15) to a single
> sum and a factor N; we must still apply the factor 1/2 to compensate
> for including each pair twice. That is, the energy of a sodium chloride
> lattice composed of a total of N ions is

I am not sure if i am getting it, so he gives the formula:
$N/2 \sum \frac{kq_{1}q_{k}}{r_{1k}}$

So basically, interpreting the formula, it is saying that the central ion is equal to, for example, the potential of the ions on the corner? Is not this wrong?

Comment: The author (who?) says that the potential energy of positive ions is the same as that of a negative ion in an infinite crystal. (The infinite sum needs a judicious order of summing to converge.)

Comment: Yes, the sum will diverge, he says it some paragraphs later. But as my doubt is how does  this first approximation works (if my interpretation was right), i just post this part. 
David Morin

Comment: @LSS I think it is true if the crystal is taken as infinite (large enough).